# Removing duplicates from a sorted array without making a new one

Tags: c#

I'm breaking my head over a coding exercise and I can't figure out the correct code.

I need to remove duplicates from a sorted array, without making a new array.

Basically, I need to turn this array:

```
1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 6 6 6 7 7
```

into this:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

My code:

```
//show original array
        int[] numbers = new int[] {1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7};


        for (int counter = 0; counter < 15; counter++)
        {
            Console.Write(numbers[counter] + " ");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();

//remove the duplicates

       for (int counter = 0; counter  < (15 - 1); counter++)
        {
           ???

        }


//show updated array
        for (int counter = 0; counter < 15; counter++)
        {
            Console.Write(numbers[counter] + " ");
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: It's a coding excercise, what do you want to achieve if somebody else will do it for you?

Comment: Itterate over the array. If the value is not 0, set all further instances of this value to 0. Then sort again but with 0 giving the highest value.

Comment: Don't look at the answer (because you won't learn anything).  Instead, think about the problem.  Get a pencil out and draw the array on a piece of paper (with little squares with numbers in them arranged horizontally).  Walk through the array with your pencil and perform the actions that you think will work.  As you are working, create a "new array" under the old one (empty squares).  As you go through, fill in the empty squares.  When you finish, you should realize that you didn't "write over" any of the numbers in the original array.  This should take you one pass thru the array

Comment: Then, do it again, but this time, writing down the steps with enough detail that you can write a program.  Some hints: Don't hard code the length, Arrays have a `Length` property.  Consider using `foreach` rather than `for`

Comment: If there is a problem that you do not know how to solve, there is an easier problem that you do know how to solve. **Solve the easier problem first**.  Then adapt the solution of the easier problem to solve the harder problem. Here's an easier problem: there's a sorted array, and it has one duplicate, and the duplicate is the last element.  Can you solve that problem?  Because if you can't solve that one, you can't solve the harder problem. But if you can solve it, then you can use that as a starting point.

Comment: Once you've solved the easier problem, here's a slightly harder version. There is more than one duplicate value, but all the duplicates are of the last item.  Can you solve that one?

Comment: @Flydog57: for is better here because we need index anyway and it's better to start from the second item

Comment: Now make a slightly harder version again. There is exactly one duplicate, but it is in the middle. Can you solve that one? **Keep doing that**.  Make easier versions of the problem that you do know how to solve. It will build your skills and your confidence, and you'll discover techniques that help you along the way to solving the harder problem.

Comment: Now, all that said, *this question should be closed because you never asked a question*.  Dumping a bunch of broken code and saying "I can't figure this out" is not a *question*. If you have a *specific* question *that has an answer*, then please ask that question. This isn't a site for doing your homework for you.

Comment: @Adassko: I didn't say "use a `foreach`", I said "Consider using `foreach`".  My goal is really to help someone who _"breaking [his] head over a coding exercise"_ by feeding him ideas.

Answer (score 0):

## Update

I gave this another go because i have OCD and it was coffee time

As pointed out, the original doesn't work in the special case that

```
i + 1 == j && numbers[i] != numbers[j]
```

p.s thanks to [@EricLippert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/88656/eric-lippert) for the code review and actually testing it.

```
int[] numbers = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 11, 12, 12, 14, 14 };

// i = unique = 0
// j = array index = 1
for (int i = 0, j = 1; j < numbers.Length; j++)
{
   // if i and j are different we can move our unique index
   if (numbers[i] != numbers[j])
      if (++i == j) // special case, lets move on ++i
         continue; // note we don't want to zero out numbers[j], so just continue
      else
         numbers[i] = numbers[j];

   // wipe the guff
   numbers[j] = 0;
}

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", numbers));
```

**Output**

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,14,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

[**Full Demo Here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/dWhIUg)

---

## Original

Its as simple as

```
for (int i = 0, j = 1; j < numbers.Length; numbers[j++] = 0)        
   if(numbers[i] != numbers[j])
      numbers[++i] = numbers[j];
```

**Output**

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

[**Full Demo Here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/F0obee)

Or a much more readable solution with out getting fancy

```
for (int i = 0, j = 1; j < numbers.Length;j++ )
{
   // is the last unique different from the current array index
   if (numbers[i] != numbers[j])
   {
      // increment the last unique, so we don't overwrite it
      i++; 
      // add the unique number at the next logical place
      numbers[i] = numbers[j];
   }

   // wipe the guff
   numbers[j] = 0;
   
}
```

Basically the idea, is move along the array, keeping an index of the last unique number

Comment: Oh i should have looked at the comments

Comment: Try to avoid clever side effecting operation solutions in C#; this sort of thing is common in C programming but it is considered by many to be poor style in C#. You can burn an extra few characters and write a solution that is more clear.

Comment: The more readable solution is considerably better. I note that the second "if" is unnecessary because it is met by the loop condition and j is not modified inside the loop.

Comment: @EricLippert hrm really? dont make me write a test!

Comment: Yeah, I realize I should have checked the correctness of the solution before complaining about the style! Try a few test cases; you'll see it.

Comment: @EricLippert ahh yep broken, thanks anyway, i think ill go back to my Saturday musings, and not try to make fancy stuff :)